# How to output copiable values in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In pine script code, I computed a value for example

```
a=(2*close-open)/2
```

How to copy it into clipboard or make it available to outside world ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [log.info()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_log.info) built-in to output the values in the log panel

```
//@version=5
indicator("log.info()")
a=(2*close-open)/2
log.info(str.tostring(a, format.mintick))
```

Add the script to the chart and open the [Pine Logs](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-logs-in-pine-script-40490/) (from the "More" menu of the Pine Editor), now you can select and copy values.

[image]